# How to fix Chrome New Tab function with extention

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a small extention which when an on-button-click, will open a URL in a new tab.

This is a snippet of part of a function:

```
var urlLink = "www.google.com";
chrome.tabs.create({ url: urlLink });
```

However, when the newtab is opened it doesn't go to google.com it puts

```
chrome-extension://**extentionID**/www.google.com
```

How do I get it only to go to www.google.com rather than call chrome-extention with the extentionID?

Also I've delcared the following in my manifest.json

```
"permissions":[
    "tabs"
],
```

Thanks.

Comment: try putting `https://` infront of url

Comment: Wow, I completly forgot that. Works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding 
    http:// 
or 
    https:// 
to the URL fixes this.